# JQuery ajax() inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, for-loop

I'm implementing default edit mode on razor view. All things works except the filling function for  drop-down list . Regarding my work i have to fill my state  drop-down list based on current selected country value at on load event. To accomplish ,i have implemented ajax inside a for loop.

## razor

```
@foreach (CustomerModel customer in Model)
    {

        <tr>
            <td class="CustomerId">
                <span id="spn_@customer.CustomerId">@customer.CustomerId</span>
            </td>
            <td class="Name">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => customer.Name,new { id =  "txtName_" + @customer.CustomerId , onkeyup = "getID(this.id)" })
                @*<input id="txtName_@customer.CustomerId" type="text" onkeyup="getID(this.id)" value="@customer.Name"/>*@
            </td>
            <td class="State">
                <select id="ddlState_@customer.CustomerId" style="width:200px;">
                    @*<option>@customer.StateName</option>*@
                </select>
            </td>

            <td class="Country">
               <select id="ddlCountry_@customer.CustomerId" onfocus="fillCountry(this.id)" onchange="fillState(this.id,this.value)" style="width:200px;">
                   <option>@customer.CountryName</option>
               </select>
            </td>
           <td>
               <button id="@customer.CustomerId" onclick="update(this.id)">Save</button>
               </td>
        </tr>
          <script>
              arrayID.push('@customer.CustomerId');
            </script>
    }
```

## Script

```
    var ids;
    var txtName;
    var txtCountry;
    var onchangeFlag = 0;
    s = 0;
    var idOf;
    var idArray = [];
    var length = 2;
    var flag = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
       // alert(arrayID);
        var ido;
        var ddlCountryID;
        var index = 0;
        var countryValue;
        var ddlStateidElement;
        var s = 0;
        var ddlStateID;
        var lenthof = arrayID.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < lenthof; i++) {
           // alert(lenthof);
            ido = arrayID[i];
            //index = ido;
            ddlCountryID = "ddlCountry_" + ido;
            ddlStateID = "ddlState_" + ido;

            countryValue = $('#' + ddlCountryID).val();
           // alert(countryValue);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/New/GetOnState",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"country":"' + countryValue + '"}',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    //  alert("success");

                   // alert(arrayID[index]);

                    ddlStateidElement = "ddlState_" + ido;
                    $('#' + ddlStateidElement).html(result);
                    //index = index + 1;

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Enter");

                }
            });
           //loopend
        }
```

Both c# code and  ajax always successful still the loop index always points the last index of the array, i don't know why the loop index fails.

## output

[image]

Comment: make async :false

Comment: thank you for response, But how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/New/GetOnState",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"country":"' + countryValue + '"}',
                dataType: "html",
                async:false,
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    //  alert("success");

                   // alert(arrayID[index]);

                    ddlStateidElement = "ddlState_" + ido;
                    $('#' + ddlStateidElement).html(result);
                    //index = index + 1;

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Enter");

                }
            });
```

Comment: Synchronous Ajax is deprecated - this will generate a warning in modern browsers. You can expect the feature to stop working at some point in future. The reason it's deprecated is because it causes terrible user experience by locking the browser UI during the request so the user cannot click anywhere. If the request(s) take a while the user might think the browser has crashed. If you need to make a series of Ajax requests in sequence the use the Promise chaining pattern

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&ei=UaGsXPPMDcP2kwXssZXgAQ&q=promise+chaining+ajax&oq=promise+chaining+ajax&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.2885.3319..3676...0.0..0.107.448.4j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0j0i20i263.plQgV3tyaD4